# Less than or equal to

Tags: batch-file

Using the pause command I found that the error is in the first line of this code:

```
if %choice% == 1 if %energy% => %m2enc% set /a enemhp=%enemhp%-%m1hpd%+%earmr%
pause
set /a energy= %energy%-%m1enc%
set /a hp= %hp%-%edefense%
set /a defense= %defense%+1
goto battle
```

So don't say that I forgot to set the energy and the m2enc, because I did just in a different section, I also tried replacing `%energy%` with `10` and `m2enc%` with `1` and it still didn't work, I tried replacing the `=>` with `>=` and with `LSQ` (apparently an alternative for less than or equal too) So I would like to know whats wrong with this part.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Since its a batch file, its most likely crashing. The error he's most ikely getting is `"Invalid use of Syntax"` or `"There is no such Path or Directory"`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In batch, the `>` is a redirection sign used to output data into a text file. The compare op's available (And recommended) for cmd are below (quoted from the `if /?` help):

```
where compare-op may be one of:

    EQU - equal
    NEQ - not equal
    LSS - less than
    LEQ - less than or equal
    GTR - greater than
    GEQ - greater than or equal
```

That should explain what you want. The only other compare-op is `==` which can be switched with the `if not` parameter. Other then that rely on these three letter ones.

Answer (score 10):

There is no `=>` for if.
Use `if %energy% GEQ %m2enc%`

See `if /?` for some other details.

Answer (score 7):

***You can use:***

EQU - equal

NEQ - not equal

LSS - less than

LEQ - less than or equal

GTR - greater than

GEQ - greater than or equal

**AVOID USING:**

()
! ~ -
* / %
+ -
<< >>
&
|
= *= /= %= += -=
  &= ^= |= <<= >>=