# How to check if the random number is between two numbers in CMD?

Tags: math, batch-file, cmd

Hi I am new with Batch programing and i want to know how you check if the random nubmer is between two numbers!

```
@echo off

set /a num = %random%
if %num% == 0-8191 goto o1
if %num% == 8191-16382 goto o2
if %num% == 16382-24573 goto o3
if %num% == 24573-32764 goto o4

:o1
msg * 1
goto end

:o2
msg * 2
goto end

:o3
msg * 3
goto end

:o4
msg * 4
goto end


:end
pause
```

I don't know what I did wrong and please if you have a better version feel free to show it :D

Thanks

Comment: My first question would be why on earth you're doing this in batch, rather than using a real programming language.  Batch is extremely limited, and is good for little more than basic automation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code from The Dark Canuck answers the comparision part of the question

For the "better" part of the question

```
set /a "num=%random% %% 4 + 1"
goto o%num%
```

Answer (score 5):

Your logic is wrong here. %num% == 0-8191 is going to subtract 8191 from 0, giving -8191 and compare that to num. With none of the gotos being triggered, you're going to fall through to o1.

You'd probably be better off doing something like this:

```
if %num% LEQ 8191 goto o1
if %num% LEQ 16382 goto o2
if %num% LEQ 24573 goto o3
if %num% LEQ 32764 goto o4
```

This checks if num is less than or equal to the given number, and goes to the appropriate label. Since the values are in increasing order, you don't need to check the lower bound-if %num% is between 16382 and 8191, it will fail the first check, fall through to the second, and skip the remainder.

For information on the comparison operators, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499797/less-than-or-equal-to).

Comment: You can't do mathematical expressions in an `if` statement so it's actually comparing whatever the number is as a string to the string `"0-8191"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question and may be preferable for easier understanding of the code in the future, when you or someone else revisits the code:

if %num% GEQ 0 if %num% LEQ 8191 goto o1