# Checking if number is smaller then 20

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know how to do batch operations like

```
    set /a var = 10
    if %var% < 20 (
    :: Do something
    )
```

But this doesn't work.  Is there a way to do operations like this?

Comment: Possible [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499797/less-than-or-equal-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the operator `LSS` will do the trick

```
set /a var = 10
    if %var% LSS 20 (
    :: Do something
    )
```

[See the link for more info](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: I just edited it, And got another error. Now, It sais "LLS Was unexpected at the time" EDIT: Woops! Typed LLS In case of LSS Now its working fine. Thank you!

Comment: LSS not LLS please :)