# Check if there's a difference between two variables

Tags: batch-file

I have two variables. `var1 = 1.0` ; `var2 = 0.9`.

I want to do this:

```
set var1=1.0
set var2=0.9

if %var1%=%var2% echo equal
if %var1%(not equal to)%var2% echo not equal
pause
```

Does anybody know what look the "not equal" symbol should look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499797/less-than-or-equal-to also gives the response you're searching for. Took me 30s of search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if "%var1%" neq "%var2%"
```

or

```
if not "%var1%"=="%var2%"
```

Type `help if` in a console window for more info.  You should also get into the habit of enclosing both sides of the `==` signs in quotation marks, in case one of the variables contains a space.

Comment: Oh thank you! I totally forgot to think.. :D. I knew that I could put "not" in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if %var1% neq %var2% echo not equal
```

there's also geq gtr lss leq and equ (greater or equal, greater, less, less or equal and equal)

But - it's best to use "quotedvariablenames" on both sides of the comparison if you're using strings that contain separators (like spaces) and you can also use

```
if /i ...
```

to compare the strings case-insensitively

and also you can use

```
if not ....
```

to negate a condition

or

```
if condition (dothis) else (dothat)
```

1. There must be a separator before the opening parenthesis of the `IF` true-condition target
2. That opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`
3. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a separator and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line
4. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line

ie

```
if condition (
 something
) else (
 someotherthing
)
```

but be careful!

batch does not support floating-point. comparing 1.0 with 0.9 will be performed as an alphabetic comparison and `2.0` will be reported as greater than `19.0` (easy with not-equal...)