# windows if command not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I tried the following command.

```
@echo off
set /a var1=2
set /a var2=4
if %var1%<%var2%
echo yesss
```

But am getting the following error.

```
2< was unexpected at this time.
```

Please can someone assist

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a couple of changes:

- Use the `LSS` operator rather than `<`
- Put the `if` statement on one line

So your script will look like this...

```
@echo off
set /a var1=2
set /a var2=4
if %var1% LSS %var2% echo yesss
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up achieving the result you wanted by using:

```
@echo off
set /a var1=2
set /a var2=4
if %var1% LSS %var2% echo yes
```

There is a helpful post relating to the comparative operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499797/less-than-or-equal-to).

### EDIT

Just saw Richard beat me to it. Still the link should be a good reference!